# Where is the Tidy 5.6 deb for Linux

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I tried installing tidy:

`sudo apt install tidy`

but it said it depended on a version of libtidy that is older than the one currently installed:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  tidy : Depends:
>   libtidy5 (= 1:5.2.0-2) but 1:5.4.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is
>   to be installed

I then tried downloading the binary of the newer version of tidy (5.6) but despite it being released in 2017, there does not seem to be a DEB download. There is source code but I'm unsure how to build for Linux.

Any idea as to why there's no DEB version of Tidy 5.6 and why there's a package in apt that has a dependency that is outdated?

Comment: OK building from source was straightforward, but the questions above remain.

Comment: The prefix *deb.sury.org* looks like not official deb-package. You can check by yourself with `apt-cache policy tidy  libtidy5`. Libtidy5 package is available for [artful and newer](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=+libtidy5&searchon=names).

Comment: ah, so I must've accidentally installed libtidy5 from a different source at some point? Can't really recall doing that ..

Comment: The output of `apt-cache policy tidy libtidy` will reveal the truth :)

Comment: Yep, it seems that way, or another package did. At any rate I don't quite know why there's no deb version of tidy 5.6